# Receiving Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to pass my task object to the controller and If I go like this:

```
var task = Task.save(task: {user_id: $scope.user.id}, $scope.newText);
```

I'm getting an error saying `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`. What's wrong with the code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Task.save(task: {user_id: $scope.user.id}` --- this part is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: The colon in `task:` is the source of this error.

Comment: How can I pass an task object with these two attributes {user_id: $scope.user.id} and $scope.newText?

Comment: @AlexanderShmatko what is the key for the second value?

Answer (score 2):

You can't give arguments names in that way. You may have wanted to pass in an object via an object initializer, in which case you need `{` and `}`:

```
var task = Task.save({task: {user_id: $scope.user.id}, someNameHere: $scope.newText});
// ------------------^-------------------------------------------------------------^
```

Note `someNameHere`, you'll need a name for that second property.

Or if `Task.save` accepts two separate arguments, remove the `task:` part:

```
var task = Task.save({user_id: $scope.user.id}, $scope.newText);
```

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect invocation of arguments

```
var task = Task.save(
    {user_id: $scope.user.id},  //parameter
    $scope.newText,             //POST data
    function(successResponse) { //success callback [optinal]
       //do success
    }, function(errorResponse){ //error callback [optinal]
       //do error
    });
```

Read [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)